# How to extract Storyboard from Viewport3d.Triggers in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a separate xaml file that looks like this :

```
<Viewport3D x:Name="ZAM3DViewport3D" ClipToBounds="true" Width="400" Height="300" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/interactivedesigner/2006" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" c:Ignorable="d">
<Viewport3D.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Viewport3D.Loaded">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Duration="Forever" FillBehavior="HoldEnd" BeginTime="0:0:0" x:Name="storyboard" d:StoryboardName="OnLoaded">
.....
```

And I have this segment of code in the program :

```
....
FileStream fs = new FileStream(mm.path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //
Viewport3D v3d = (Viewport3D)XamlReader.Load(fs);
....
```

I would like to know how I can extract the storyboard from the EventTrigger.Actions. I guess it would look like this:

```
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)v3d.Triggers[0]....
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a `Storyboard` somewhere else beside the `Triggers` define it as resource. Then you can reference it in `BeginStoryboard` using `StaticResource` and in code you can find it with [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource.aspx) or get it directly from the `Resources` property.

```
<Viewport3D.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ThatSb">...</Storyboard>
<Viewport3D.Resources>
<!-- .... -->
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ThatSb}"/>
```

```
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)v3d.Resources["ThatSb"];
```

---

The not so nice alternative is actually casting your way down, something like

```
var trigger = (EventTrigger)v3d.Triggers[0];
var beginSb = (BeginStoryboard)trigger.Actions[0];
var sb = beginSb.Storyboard;
```